# List Index out of Range while constructing a Graphic

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm having an error:

"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\Task4", line 13, in 
    if (y[i]-3)

With the following code:

```
from numpy import*
from matplotlib import pyplot
import random 
Player1 = raw_input("Player 1 Name:")
Player2 = raw_input("Player 2 Name:")
pyplot.axis([0,8000,0,200])
a = random.randint(0,101)
x = range(8000)
y = [a]`enter code here`
i=0
while i<len(x):
    b = random.randint(0,101)
    if (y[i]-3)<b and b<(y[i]+3):
        y.append(b)
    i+=1

pyplot.plot(x,y)
pyplot.show()
```

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Check my updated answer for a simple hack! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you intended to do the following.

```
if(y[0]-3)<b and b<(y[0]+3) ...
```

or

```
if(a-3)<b and b<(a+3) ...
```

The `y=[a]` statement generates a single element `list` containing only the generated `randint`.

There is a better trick for this in Python. Python, being awesome, can understand the following too

```
if (a-3) < b < (a+3) ...
```